# Compare last 10 characters in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, character, match

I have two tables:  contacts and messages.

contacts has: person, address

messages has: address, message

address can have more than 10 characters.

The address in contacts might have 13 characters: abc9995551212

The address in messages might have 11 characters: e9995551212

How can I compare the last 10 characters from both addresses

and if they match create a view with:

contacts.person, messages.address, messages.message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `RIGHT` function can be used to return the n right (last) characters of a string. From there on, it's just a matter of joining:

```
SELECT contacts.person, messages.address, messages.message
FROM   contacts
JOIN   messages ON RIGHT(messages.address, 10) = RIGHT(contacts.address, 10)
```